# Answer truncated, user info formatted as code

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, markdown

The answer got cut off, the user information looks different and some HTML tags seem to be in a wrong position. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107987/897024) in [Most efficient way to increment a Map value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java):

[image: Truncated post]

The part at the **?** got cut off and is only visible in edit mode. No special characters are there and the post also isn't unusually long. Maybe a cut off `code` closing tag got auto closed or something, it results in a pretty weird `</table> </code> </td> </tr>` markup just before the comments.

Comment: Added some spaces and saved and all is well in the world...

Comment: It seems to be working fine in the revision history view, which is strange since the parser (ought to be ) the same..

Comment: @Tim ManishEarth: That's because revisions are always rendered on the fly, whereas the final HTML renditions of answers are generated at the moment they were last saved, then cached. Such an issue occurred here probably because of a bug with the renderer at that time. This has been covered on meta before but I'm having a hard time finding it. It should have been mentioned by balpha.

Comment: @Bolt ahh, right--makes sense..

Comment: The HTML is cached, so if there was an error in the rendering code it would be preserved until the post is edited. This question was last edited in Sept **08**.